# Handling async operation in mongoose virtual property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a virtual property on the users schema called **debt**

the **debt** property is to return the sum aggregate of each user total debt from the **Bill model**

But the virtual field **debt** keeps returning *Promise {  }*

Here is my code sample:

```
userSchema.virtual('debt').get(async function () {
    const bills = await this.model('Bill').aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [{ 'user._id': this._id }, { balance: { $gt: 0 } }]
            }
        },
        {
            $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$balance" } }
        }
    ]);
    console.log(bills) // [{_id: null, total: theSummedValue }]
    return bills[0].total; // Promise { <pending> }
});
```

how can I return theSummedValue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [issue#1894](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1894) and [issue#5762](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5762)

> virtuals are just getters/setters, which are assumed to be synchronous

You can add a custom [instance method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) instead.

E.g.(*"mongoose": "^7.2.1"*)

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
});
userSchema.method('dept', async function () {
    console.log(this);
    // @ts-ignore
    const result = await mongoose.model('bill').aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [{ 'user._id': this._id }, { balance: { $gt: 0 } }],
            },
        },
        {
            $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: '$balance' } },
        },
    ]);
    return result[0].total;
});
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

const billSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    balance: Number,
    user: userSchema,
});
const Bill = mongoose.model('bill', billSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        await Promise.all([User, Bill].map((m) => m.collection.drop()));
        // seed
        const [user1, user2] = await User.create([{ name: 'Nick' }, { name: 'Jack' }]);
        await Bill.create([
            { balance: 100, user: user1 },
            { balance: 200, user: user1 },
            { balance: 0, user: user1 },
            { balance: 50, user: user2 },
        ]);
        //@ts-ignore
        const dept = await user1.dept();
        console.log("Nick's dept: ", dept);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Output:

```
Mongoose: users.drop()
Mongoose: bills.drop()
Mongoose: users.insertOne({ name: 'Nick', _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976083"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: users.insertOne({ name: 'Jack', _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976084"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: bills.insertOne({ balance: 100, user: { name: 'Nick', _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976083"), __v: 0 }, _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976087"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: bills.insertOne({ balance: 200, user: { name: 'Nick', _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976083"), __v: 0 }, _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976089"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: bills.insertOne({ balance: 0, user: { name: 'Nick', _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976083"), __v: 0 }, _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b497608b"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: bills.insertOne({ balance: 50, user: { name: 'Jack', _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976084"), __v: 0 }, _id: ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b497608d"), __v: 0}, {})
{ name: 'Nick', _id: new ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976083"), __v: 0 }
Mongoose: bills.aggregate([ { '$match': { '$and': [ { 'user._id': new ObjectId("6498f33d24d77a71b4976083") }, { balance: { '$gt': 0 } } ] } }, { '$group': { _id: null, total: { '$sum': '$balance' } } }], {})
Nick's dept:  300
```

Comment: @OlisaAgbafor `resDTO = { user, dept }`, the frontend guy could use this DTO